# When snapping to faces, is it possible to snap with an offset?

Tags: modifiers, snapping, shrinkwrap

I frequently use the snap-to tool modifier, typically (but not always) to the closest face, when I'm modeling clothing.

[image: Snap To Tool Modifier]

While this is very useful, I consistently have to make adjustments afterwards, usually with Alt+S (scale along normal), to remove intersections with some stray faces.

It would be incredibly useful if, like with the Shrink Wrap modifier, I could simply snap to the face plus an offset.

[image]

It's useful and obvious enough that I'm not the least bit certain that I actually *can't* do this, and am not simply failing to see the option. Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Michael, As you say this would be useful.. but I think the best way to do it is to have a shrinkwrap modifier on the clothing using `Outside Surface` and toggle `On Cage` so it shows as you do the remeshing on the clothes.